# No sound after PulseAudio reinstall

Tags: sound, virtualbox, pulseaudio, re-installation

I encountered an audio bug and [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/689106) it on Launchpad. There I was asked to reinstall PulseAudio.

That sounded dangerous, so I tried it on a VirtualBox virtual machine I had lying around. (this VM had no sound problems at all). And indeed, after I did a naive `sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio` -> reboot -> `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`, the VM has no sound any more.

Strangely, everything looks OK. There is nothing muted (I unmuted every single playback chanel in alsamixer just in case). The driver for the sound card is recognized and loaded, aplay plays sound files without producing an error, and when I installed and opened PulseAudio Volume Meter, playing a sound resulted in the volume indicator changing with the sound. Only there is nothing coming out of the loudspeakers. This isn't a hardware problem either, because the sound in the host system is functioning.

I tried to configure PulseAudio as described on [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio#ALSA%20Configuration) of the Ubuntu wiki, but had no success.

I am afraid to try the reinstall on my real system until I know how to do it without causing a problem. Did I miss a configuration step somewhere? Should I have reinstalled in some other way?

Both guest and host systems are Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the ideas.

It must have been a problem in the communication between host and Virtual Box. In the virtual machine settings, I set the sound mode from "Pulse Audio" to "Alsa" and I got sound. Then I toggled it back to Pulse Audio - and the VM still had sound.

Sometimes the answer is so easy I want to chew on something---

Answer (score 4):

Please amend your question to include the most current information from `pactl stat` in a Terminal and from the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo.  As an aside, I've contacted Fabio (the person who asked you to reinstall pulse) with clarifications to his triaging process.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I solved the problem on the virtual box. Thank you for talking to Fabio, he said I don't have to reinstall on the main system, and I am happy about that.  

Is posting the information you requested also relevant to the initial bug, or only to the missing sound in the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, more information would still be useful, because your symptom is still arguably a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete `~/.pulse/` in your home directory where there may rest some erroneous per-user settings. Don't worry it will immediately be rewritten with default settings when the PA daemon restarts.

To both, check if pulseaudio is running at all, and to start it manually if not type

```
pulseaudio
```

in a terminal. You will get an error if `pulseaudio` is already there.

For your bug you may want to check if settings in your `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` are o.k., especially look for the entry:

```
flat-volumes = no
```

If this entry is set to `yes` (by default) PA will always try to output at maximum level. For detail see the [PulseAudio Daemon manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/pulse-daemon.conf.5.html)

Comment: Thank you for both ideas. It turns out that the problem described here was a minor VirtualBox problem. The initial bug persists, flat-volumes is set to no. But it was a good idea to check this config file, I didn't even know it existed.

Answer (score 1):

Go here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578

Do **Part A** only. That should fix the problem in no time.

Comment: Sadly, this did not help. The packages listed in the guide apwere already installed on the system, and the sound card was already the default device in the PA volume control. So I just toggled it and restarted the VM, but the problem is still there.