# No Sound in inbuilt speakers?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am using ubuntu 11.10 . last night i am searching some help on using my headfone mic . but i found nothing. then i install pavcontrol and remove that  . by this cmd :

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

then  i uninstall that

```
 sudo apt-get purge pavucontrol
```

but i found something which says me it will use start using ur mic 
then i try this :

```
sudo apt-get install paman padevchooser paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter
```

but some package error comes then i leave this and move ahead error was :

**Package padevchooser is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'padevchooser' has no installation candidate**

then after restart my sound is not working but i am able to hear sound on my *sound system* & *headfones* only problem is i am not able to use my system inbuilt speakers .

i check my alsamixer & sound setting nothing is mute everything is working fine

my `pactl stat`

```
Currently in use: 1 blocks containing 64.0 KiB bytes total.
Allocated during whole lifetime: 6707 blocks containing 21.8 MiB bytes total.
Sample cache size: 0 B
Server String: unix:/home/gaurav/.pulse/bc36bc434b13df8339b314820000000d-runtime/native
Library Protocol Version: 24
Server Protocol Version: 24
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 11
Tile Size: 65496
User Name: gaurav
Host Name: Gaurav
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 1.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
Cookie: 66d0:548d
```

i also check whether pulseausio is running or not :

```
pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

is there anything is did worng i tried with this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17101/no-sound-after-pulseaudio-reinstall) But nothing helps me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `pavucontrol` (if it was installed correctly) and check the configuration tab, you need to select one of the **duplex** profiles if you want to channel the sound to 2 different connectors.

[image]

After you have selected the profile go to the **output** tab and for each device on the list set the desired volume.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pereria: Just re-install pavcontrol and i selected analog setro duplex . but problem is when i open alsamixer its shows me that speaker is mute when i unmute that . then my system sound works fine but when i restart that is again shows me that my system speakers is mute

Comment: Pereia : How i adjust on `pavucontrol`. guide me

Comment: Great news ;) regards